# How to properly take good care of your laptop battery if you're not really going to use it a lot?

Tags: laptop, battery-life

I probably never ever have my batteries inside my laptops except in extremely rare situations (those on average happen something like once per two years, if at all) when I need to unplug one of my laptops for just a few minutes for testing purposes (I might be testing my Internet connectivity through a cable too short to run it all the way from the router in the hall to my room, so I need to move the laptop instead because there's no spare wall socket around there). My home laptop computers always run plugged to the wall socket. What are the best practices out there regarding proper use and care of laptop batteries when you hardly ever use them?

What I've heard is that if you're going to use your laptop battery only occasionally, the best thing for you to do would be to discharge it to when only about 60% is left, pop it out of the computer and stash it away somewhere safe. That way the battery will presumably last longer. What do you think about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you re only worried about the battery, your advice about partly discharging it and popping it out of the computer is good - you will want to periodically (every few months) top it back up to the 60% or so mark to keep it in best condition.   You also want to keep it relatively cool - the cooler the better [ but, I'd imagine, above freezing ].

That said, you may want to reconsider and look at the whole picture. If you have a laptop, your best bet is to keep the battery plugged in as it helps filter the power (and provides sudden outage protection).  Also, unless you keep it in unrealistic conditions you will loose - nominaly - 20% capacity per year just by having it sit on the shelf - factor this against how long the battery will last, and I would not worry too much about it if its always plugged in.

Depending on the laptop, you may be able to (in BIOS) tell it to charge to no more then 80 or 90 % to prolong battery life as well.   Thats probably what I'd do if its an option - I certainly would not run without it.

Comment: I was in the process of writing virtually the same answer and you beat me to it.